# Remove google maps circle overlay within function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've redone this code so it's shorter, but basically I'm trying to add a circle with left click and remove it with right click. The radius.setMap(null) works only if it's not inside a function.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100%% }
      body { height: 100%%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100%% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.467726,153.026633);
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: centerlatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: centerlatlng,
                                            map: map,
                                            title:"Hello World!"});   

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', updateCircle);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'rightclick', removeRadius);

    function removeRadius(){
        radius.setMap(null);}

    function updateCircle(){
        var radius = new google.maps.Circle({map: map,
                                            radius: 400,
                                            center: centerlatlng,
                                            fillOpacity: 0});}      
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%%; height:50%%"></div>
  <body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using double percentage signs everywhere? (%%)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to take them out. I'm using google app-engine with python and needed to cancel out the percentage signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radius variable is local to the function updateCircle(). Make it global instead.

```
//Global variables
var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.467726,153.026633);
var radius;


function updateCircle(){
      // do not use the 'var' keyword here
        radius = new google.maps.Circle({map: map,
                                            radius: 400,
                                            center: centerlatlng,
                                            fillOpacity: 0});}      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**radius** is declared locally in the function `updateCircle()`, so it cannot be used in `removeRadius()`.

If you move the declaration from `updateCircle()` into the containing function `initialize()`, both `updateCircle()` and `removeRadius()` will be able to see it without making it global;

```
function initialize() {
    var radius;
    var mapOptions = {...

    function updateCircle(){
        radius = new google.maps.Circle({map: map, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in google map V3:

```
var shape=null;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, "circlecomplete", function(circle) {
    shape=circle;
});
```

after assigning variable for this when you want to remove this circle just call this function:

```
function removeOverlay {
    shape.setMap(null);
}
```

you just have to save an object returned by google in a specific variable......

hope this will help you.